# How to train this neural network?

Tags: neural-network, xor

I programmed a simple back propagation NN. Here is the code snippet:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {

            /// i1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            //i2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            //desired = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);

            Random rnd = new Random();
            i1 = rnd.Next(0, 1);
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            i2 = rnd1.Next(0, 1);
            if(i1 == 1 && i2 == 1)
            {
                desired = 0;
            }
            else if(i1 == 0&&i2 == 0)
            {
                desired = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                desired = 1;
            }



            //hidden layer hidden values
            h1 = i1 * w1 + i2 * w2; //i1*w1+i2*w2
            h2 = i1 * w3 + i2 * w4;//i1*w3+i2*w4
            h3 = i1 * w5 + i2 * w6;//i1*w5+i2*w6;

            //hidden layer hidden values

            //VALUE OF HIDDEN LAYER
            h1v = Sigmoid(h1);
            h2v = Sigmoid(h2);
            h3v = Sigmoid(h3);
            //VALUE OF HIDDEN LAYER            

            //output final
            output = h1v * w7 + h2v * w8 + h3v * w9;
            outputS = Sigmoid(output);
            //output final

            //BACKPROPAGATION

            //MARGIN ERROR
            Error = desired - outputS; //desired-cena jaka ma byc OutputS-zgadnienta cena

            //Margin Error

            //DElta output sum
            deltaoutputsum = Derivative(output) * Error; //output bez sigmoida i error
                                                         //Delta output sum

            //weight of w7,w8,w9.
            w7b = w7; //0.3
            w8b = w8; // 0.5
            w9b = w9;// 0.9
            w7 = w7 + deltaoutputsum * h1v; //waga w7
            w8 = w8 + deltaoutputsum * h2v; //waga w8
            w9 = w9 + deltaoutputsum * h3v; //waga w9
                                            //weights of w7,w8,w9.

            //DELTA HIDDEN SUm
            h1 = deltaoutputsum * w7b * Derivative(h1);
            h2 = deltaoutputsum * w8b * Derivative(h2);
            h3 = deltaoutputsum * w9b * Derivative(h3);
            //DELTA HIDDEN SUM

            //weights 1,2,3,4,5,6
            w1 = w1 - h1 * i1;
            w2 = w2 - h1 * i2;
            w3 = w3 - h2 * i1;
            w4 = w4 - h2 * i2;
            w5 = w5 - h3 * i1;
            w6 = w6 - h3 * i2;
            label1.Text = outputS.ToString();
            label2.Text = w1.ToString();
            label3.Text = w2.ToString();
            label4.Text = w3.ToString();
            label5.Text = w4.ToString();
            label6.Text = w5.ToString();
            label7.Text = w6.ToString();
            label8.Text = w7.ToString();
            label9.Text = w8.ToString();
            label10.Text = w9.ToString();
            //weights 1,2,3,4,5,6

        }
```

It is very simple to solve XOR problems. But I'dont now how to predict the output. Here i must provide answear to set the weights, but how to predict? 
It train 10,000 on random training data.
Now when it is trained how to predict the answear?
Please help.
Sorry for my english but I dont now it very well.

h1-3 are weights of nodes
h1v are values of nodes
w1-10 are weights

Comment: what do you mean, you know what xor operation does, you know the inputs, so you know what you should be getting out.

Comment: Yea, but here I must provide a variable desired,but after training it should now that variable without training. And I don't now how to write it

Comment: Say we have a i1 = 1 and i2 = 1 and desired =0. Now ii run this with different data 10,000 to train this. After training I provide i1 = 1 and i2=0 and now computer must predict the desired variable without training, but this code can only train and I'm asking to tell what code can I use to predict desired variable.

Comment: Ok, so you are asking how to get the trained network out of your for loop?  That should be kind of obvious...  You just use one iteration of this loop in isolation with out modifying the weights.  Forward propagate your values only.

Comment: no, when I provide input 1 =1 and input 2 =1 and desired = 0 then it sets the weights. But when I provide input 1 = 1 and input 2 = 0 then I want the neural network to tell me desired value(1)

Comment: wait are you telling me you aren't training on 1 and 0 output, and only 1 and 1 ouput and that you aren't getting the correct answer when you *do* run it in isolation?  It is not possible for any thing known to man to do that...   Its like telling someone XOR with true and true = false, now figure out the rest.  They won't know how to perform the rest of the operations.

Comment: No, I'm training on random inputs not only 1 and 1 but when i train on 1 and 1 and then i start training on 0 and 1 the weights are changing and then when it is trying to predict the value it alway return 1. I dont now I must save the weights ?

Comment: Did you make this on your own, is this for a class? (it is still a valid question if it is, it is just important to know how much of this is your understanding) i might know what the problem is.

Comment: I writed it myself. I'm 14 yers old so I don't know C# very well but I was writing it myself for one week. It is not from internet.

Comment: I just don't know is it good and where is the problem

Comment: When I provide 2 inputs and output And i do this 10 times then it sets weights correct and answear is correct. But now i want to write a code to predict the output like neural network

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense, Its been a while since I've worked with Neural networks, but I think an issue is that the current implementation might be changing stuff too fast. Your delta sum takes into account the full margin of error. This could punish differences too much. This would cause consecutive tests on the same 2 inputs to be correct, but not much else to be correct.  You may need another value, a "learning rate" to multiply with `Error` in `deltaoutputsum`.  Also, what is the implementation of  `Derivative` how is it finding the derivative of a scalar value?

Comment: I don't know what is scalar value.

Comment: public double Derivative(double x)
{
    double s = Sigmoid(x);
    return 1 - (Math.Pow(s, 2));
} this is the function derivative

Comment: The code is activated when i click the button. I'm providing 2 inputs and output. I click button 10 times and then the answear is correct. But when I change the inputs and output I must also click 10 times. The weights are changing and now i want to predict the output without knowing it. I must save the weights? If i provided inputs 1 and 1 and output 0 the weights are set to this inputs and output but when i change it to other the weights are still for 1 and 1 and 0. So I can predict only this XOR

Comment: IF i want to predict output I can't calculate error becouse i dont have output

Comment: The derivative of sigmoid is not `1 - sigmoid(x)^2`, but `sigmoid(x) - sigmoid(x)^2` [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78575/derivative-of-sigmoid-function-sigma-x-frac11e-x).   Also you should only have one set of persistent weights, If I understand the code, you already have values for the weights outside the loop, and the loop starts, updates them, and then you have the final value of the weights after wards which you can use with out training.  When you do prediction you just use the weights after training, I think the issue is training, which is why I talked about error

Comment: Yes, but I have weights only for one inputs (1 and 1), when I provide input for 1 and 0 i have weights for one and 0. And somone provide input 1 and 1. How i can provide weights for 1 and 1 not for 1 and 0?

Comment: The idea is that the weights are not specific for each input, the weights are the same for all inputs at the end and should give the correct results.  I suggest you look at this [guys page](https://stevenmiller888.github.io/mind-how-to-build-a-neural-network/).  The end goal is to have *one* set of weights that work for all inputs and can get an acceptable output.

Comment: Ok so lets say i have weights example 1,1 2,2 3,3 and they should work for all inputs? Becouse when i set inputs to 1 and 1 and weights are set then i have 0.00222 do it is good but when i change to 1 and 0 then if i click one time IT only change small amount from 0.002 to 0.0023. i must click 100 times to get IT correct

Comment: if you have weights `w0`, `w1`, `w2`, `w3`, `w4`, `w5`, at the end of doing your training over the input values `[1,1][1,0][0,1][0,0]`  with expected outputs `[0, 1, 1, 0]` after `N` runs, a correctly functioning neural network should work for any XOR inputs you give after that point, and you shouldn't be modifying the weights after training is done.  Your training simply doesn't work correctly if those weights aren't correct after training on each of those four inputs after `N = 1000` times.

Comment: Ok thanks for help. Do you see where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in how you are training.

Do the following and I believe your program will be correct

- Try training each of the data sets one after another instead of random, random works for continuous floating point values, but when you are working with XOR, you might run into issues where training too much on one or two sets of values (because of the nature of random) will cause issues moving the wieghts back toward a value that works with other input XOR values. So train on [1,1], then immediately [1,0] then [0,1] and then [0, 0] and repeat over and over.
- Make sure the derivative function is correct; the derivative of a sigmoid should be `sigmoid(x) - sigmoid(x)^2`
- name your hidden sum values something different than `h1`, `h2` etc.. if you use that for the hidden node input values.

If you do those things, it appears you should have something exactly mathematically equivalent to what ["how to build a neural-network"](https://stevenmiller888.github.io/mind-how-to-build-a-neural-network/) has.

I would also recommend having values that aren't persistent *initialized inside* your loop instead of *outside*.  I may be wrong, but I don't think any value except your `w1` `w2` `w3` etc... values need to be persistent through every training iteration.  Not doing this causes hard to catch bugs and make reading the code harder since you can't guarantee variables aren't being modified elsewhere.

Comment: yes I was learning from steven miller a month ago. I was testing my network from his values to check if this works. Thanks for your help. Now it is working :D